Laravel morph relationship not retrieving end model
I'm working with a Laravel 11 project and need to link models together with a morph relationship. I've opted for a linking table called ModelHasModels which defines:

source_id - id of the source model
source_type - string for the source model
target_id - id of the target model
target_type - string for the target model

I have various models, a Site model and Affiliate model. affiliates can be linked to many sites, and sites would have affiliates.
I've defined my models, and inserted a row into the model_has_models table, but when querying the Site to get the affiliates I get nothing:
Querying:
Site::with('affiliates')->get(); <-- returns empty affiliates

Here's the definition of each model:
Site
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUlids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;

class Site extends Model
{
    use HasUlids, HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'url',
        'is_enabled'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'is_enabled' => 'boolean'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Define all of the related models for this model
     */
    public function models(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(ModelHasModel::class, 'source');
    }

    /**
     * Define all of the affiliates linked to this model
     */
    public function affiliates(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Affiliate::class, 'source', 'model_has_models', 'source_id', 'target_id');
    }

    /**
     * Link the model to the user
     */
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

Affiliate
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUlids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;

class Affiliate extends Model
{
    use HasUlids, HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'api_key',
        'is_enabled'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'is_enabled' => 'boolean'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Define all of the related models for this model
     */
    public function models(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(ModelHasModel::class, 'target');
    }

    /**
     * All of the sites that link to this model
     */
    public function sites(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Site::class, 'target', 'model_has_models', 'target_id', 'source_id');
    }

    /**
     * Link the model to the user
     */
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

ModelHasModel
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUlids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

class ModelHasModel extends Model
{
    use HasUlids, HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'source_id',
        'source_type',
        'target_id',
        'target_type'
    ];

    /**
     * Define the model that this model is derived from
     */
    public function source(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Define the model that this model must link to
     */
    public function target(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

And I've created an entry in the model_has_models like the following:
INSERT INTO `model_has_models` (`id`, `source_type`, `source_id`, `target_type`, `target_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    ('01HY083NK2THPY7A9M4SMKVVY3', 'App\\Models\\Site', '01hy07w8r8hc2v70h2zvbb6fz2', 'App\\Models\\Affiliate', '01hy07wp70a589gwpbqv0neh1a', '2024-05-16 08:26:10', '2024-05-16 08:26:12');

What am I missing?

that is not how this relation works at all https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

your linking table would be like: 'affiliate_id', 'affiliatable_id', 'affiliatable_type'

In my example I've just used Site and Affiliate as a small test case. I have other models as well: Form, Inbound, Domain, all of which must link to one or more sites, and a site may have one or more of these models. thus why I've got this "ModelHasModel" table. How do I get this table to work? I feel I'm not too far away and need to maybe change one or two things.

The link you've attached I am aware of, however, this is for one thing. I need a linking table that can work for many models

all of which must link to one or more sites, and a site may have one or more of these models - so why not create a siteable table with site_id, sitable_type, sitable_id, where sitable would be any of the models you mentioned?

That's true. Because I want potential expansion for different models to link to one another, not strictly just sites. Additionally, could provide a cod example as an answer for me to try and vote please.

I find model_has_models unnecessary and irrelevant and does not comply with how laravel's many to many relation should work. If you are new to laravel, then first do a dummy project with many to many relations for 2 models (without morph - which is for more than 2 models). After getting the hang of it, you can try many to many with morph again @RyanH
